# WP 7.1 Live Tiles "Unpinned" listener

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, tile

I'm playing with live tiles on Mango and it's all nice and all. User can delete secondary tiles and everything, but if the user "unpins" a secondary tile is there a way to know that tile is gone?

**I want to persist data about an object when it's pinned. And I want to be able to delete that data when it's unpinned (from the start menu).**

Is there something that's fired when a secondary tile tied to your app is unpinned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no event that is fired when the secondary tile is unpinned. However, you can check for your application's active live tiles by querying the [ShellTile.ActiveTiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltile.activetiles%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) collection. Not knowing your scenario you could run this check during the various application lifecycle events.

There is a decent screen cast on how to update tiles and use secondary tiles over on [http://msdev.com](http://www.msdev.com/Directory/Description.aspx?eventId=2005) as well as a [How-To on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202979%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). Both of these show examples of using the ShellTile.ActiveTiles API.

Comment: Yeah, that was also the conclusion I got to. So what I ended up doing was: if the user create a live tile, it also adds to the "favorite" list. If they clear the list as a whole, or individually, it queries the ShellTile.ActiveTiles collection as you mentioned, and get rid of those if an association exists.